# Export into Excel if rowModelType={'viewport'}

Tags: excel, export, viewport

If AgGridReact rowModelType is viewport (the mode for massive volume of data) then export into Excel does not work correctly - both methods of data export - from context menu or using grid.current.api.exportDataAsExcel({ exportedRows: 'all' }); from code return the same result - the first 20 ... 30 records are exported only. Is it a bug or real working example exists?

Thank you.

Method grid.current.api.exportDataAsExcel({ exportedRows: 'all' }); from JavaScript code was used but the same the first 30 records instead of all (about 1,000) have been exported into Excel file.